# How is `require '<gem>'` working without bundler?

Tags: ruby

I've got a script that requires the sequel gem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "BEFORE:", $LOAD_PATH.sort
require 'sequel'
puts "AFTER:", $LOAD_PATH.sort

puts self.method(:require).owner
```

I expected it to fail without using bundler to add the gem's lib directory to the load path, but it succeeded!

In the output, you can plainly see the path is getting added by something:

```
BEFORE:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
AFTER:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sequel-4.26.0/lib
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-linux
Kernel
```

I even checked the method owner to see if `require` is resolving to something other than Ruby's built-in `Kernel::require` method, but it's clearly coming from `Kernel`.

What's going on here?

(Using Ruby 2.2.3.)

Answer (score 2):

This is handled by RubyGems and has nothing to do with Bundler.

Comment: Just did some testing with using require with/without bundler while having two different versions of a gem installed and specifying the older one in my Gemfile.  So, to sum up what I've learned: (1) ruby will automatically search for installed gems and add their load paths, defaulting to the latest installed version of each gem, whereas (2) bundler will ensure the path for the specified version is first in LOAD_PATH so you get the right one.  Is that correct?

Comment: Bundler mostly changes the `GEM_PATH` so that RubyGems will look in the path managed by Bundler, similarly to how RVM etc. change the `PATH` so that the shell will look in the path managed by RVM.

Comment: I thought Bundler changes LOAD_PATH.  Certainly something is.  UPDATE: Was curious about GEM_PATH, so I started IRB and evaluated `ENV['GEM_PATH']`, and got `nil`.  Then I required 'bundler/setup` and evalutated it again, and got empty string (`""`).

Comment: Yes, that's how RubyGems works. RubyGems changes the `LOAD_PATH` so that `require` will look in the path managed by RubyGems. It also overrides `require`, so that instead of erroring out if it can't find a path, it will first check whether that path exists in some Gem somewhere, and add that Gem to the `LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: RubyGems also has a Ruby API, quite likely Bundler is using that API to communicate with RubyGems instead of shell environment variables.

Comment: Did more digging... I see that `rubygems` is a package that comes with Ruby, but because it's part of stdlib, it can't evolve quickly (assumption), so there's a gem called `rubygems-update` (https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update) (https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems) that is more frequently updated -- and I've got the latest one installed (2.4.8).  However, I still don't get how any of this is working without first requiring rubygems.  Stdlib packages don't get loaded implicitly, do they?  (I still have to `require 'logger'`, for example.)

Comment: For the curious... here's where `Kernel::require` gets overridden in rubygems-update: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb

Comment: You have it somewhat backwards: RubyGems has always been a separate package. It was added to Ruby in 1.9, which is why you don't need to `require` it. (Actually, by default, Ruby includes only the parts that are needed to `require` Gems, other parts, e.g. for installing or creating Gems still need to be `require`d.) The `rubygems-update` package has also always existed, it is needed because, well, RubyGems itself can't be a Gem, otherwise how would you install it?

Comment: You actually do have to explicitly require stdlib packages to use them.  Apparently, rubygems is the exception, as it's always loaded implicitly: https://gist.github.com/odigity/767d3a5ab136b4845a7f